# Is it possible to have perception without reification?

Tags: personal-experience, perception, reification

Sometimes some visual or auditory sense perception gives the taste of no-self. Like, the ego dissolves for a moment and you feel tremendous oneness with existence. For e.g. while looking at the sunset or the night sky, or listening to the rain.

But such states don't last for long. So just want to understand what might be happening. I think what happens is that you perceive but there is no reification, but that is what I think.

Is it possible to have perception without reification? And is this state the same as "***Yatha-bhuta-nana-dassana***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to have perception without reification?

Yes. The sutta [MN 1](https://suttacentral.net/mn1/en/bodhi) below shows this and presents the difference between unenlightened persons and the enlightened ones.

The unenlightened:

> “Here, bhikkhus, an untaught ordinary person, who has no regard for
> noble ones and is unskilled and undisciplined in their Dhamma, who has
> no regard for true men and is unskilled and undisciplined in their
> Dhamma, perceives earth as earth. Having perceived earth as earth, he
> conceives himself as earth, he conceives himself in earth, he
> conceives himself apart from earth, he conceives earth to be ‘mine,’
> he delights in earth. Why is that? Because he has not fully understood
> it, I say.
>
> “He perceives the seen as the seen. Having perceived the seen as the
> seen, he conceives himself as the seen, he conceives himself in the
> seen, he conceives himself apart from the seen, he conceives the seen
> to be ‘mine,’ he delights in the seen. Why is that? Because he has not
> fully understood it, I say.
>
> “He perceives the heard as the heard. Having perceived the heard as
> the heard, he conceives himself as the heard, he conceives himself in
> the heard, he conceives himself apart from the heard, he conceives the
> heard to be ‘mine,’ he delights in the heard. Why is that? Because he
> has not fully understood it, I say.
>
> “He perceives Nibbāna as Nibbāna. Having perceived Nibbāna as Nibbāna,
> he conceives himself as Nibbāna, he conceives himself in Nibbāna, he
> conceives himself apart from Nibbāna, he conceives Nibbāna to be
> ‘mine,’ he delights in Nibbāna. Why is that? Because he has not fully
> understood it, I say.

The enlightened:

> “Bhikkhus, a bhikkhu who is an arahant with taints destroyed, who has
> lived the holy life, done what had to be done, laid down the burden,
> reached his own goal, destroyed the fetters of being, and is
> completely liberated through final knowledge, he too directly knows
> earth as earth. Having directly known earth as earth, he does not
> conceive himself as earth, he does not conceive himself in earth, he
> does not conceive himself apart from earth, he does not conceive earth
> to be ‘mine,’ he does not delight in earth. Why is that? Because he
> has fully understood it, I say.
>
> “He too directly knows water as water…Nibbāna as Nibbāna…Why is that?
> Because he has fully understood it, I say.
>
> “Bhikkhus, the Tathāgata, too, accomplished and fully enlightened,
> directly knows earth as earth. Having directly known earth as earth,
> he does not conceive himself as earth, he does not conceive himself in
> earth, he does not conceive himself apart from earth, he does not
> conceive earth to be ‘mine,’ he does not delight in earth. Why is
> that? Because he has understood that delight is the root of suffering,
> and that with being as condition there is birth, and that for whatever
> has come to be there is ageing and death. Therefore, bhikkhus, through
> the complete destruction, fading away, cessation, giving up, and
> relinquishing of cravings, the Tathāgata has awakened to supreme full
> enlightenment, I say.
>
> “He too directly knows water as water…Nibbāna as Nibbāna…Why is that?
> Because he has understood that delight is the root of suffering, and
> that with being as condition there is birth, and that for whatever has
> come to be there is ageing and death. Therefore, bhikkhus, through the
> complete destruction, fading away, cessation, giving up, and
> relinquishing of cravings, the Tathāgata has awakened to supreme full
> enlightenment, I say.”
>
> [MN 1](https://suttacentral.net/mn1/en/bodhi)

But why is it this way?

In the following sutta and commentary, Ven. Thanissaro explained that reification is rooted in the mental idea of the self i.e.  "I am the thinker". So, everything other than the self is objectified and classified into non-self objects based on their relationship to the self.

However, for the enlightened, self-view and conceit has been destroyed. Thus, they see things as they truly are.

For e.g. if you're a vegan, you may look at a meat dish and cringe. If you're meat lover, you may look at a meat dish and salivate.

But an arahant will just see it as it is, without reacting based on greed, aversion and delusion. The arahant still has the non-clinging aggregate of perception (please see Ven. Thanissaro's [footnote to Iti 44](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.2.028-049.than.html#fn-044.1) and [SN 22.48](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.48/en/bodhi)), using which, he can identify what is sensed, without reifying (concept-proliferating) it relative to the self.

> "I ask the kinsman of the Sun, the great seer,
> about seclusion & the state of peace.
> Seeing in what way is a monk unbound,
> clinging to nothing in the world?"
> "He should put an entire stop
> to the root of objectification-classifications:
> 'I am the thinker.'
>
> **Commentary by Ven. Thanissaro:**
> On objectification-classifications
> and their role in leading to conflict, see [Snp 4.11](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.11.than.html) and the
> introduction to [MN 18](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.018.than.html). The perception, "I am the thinker" lies at
> the root of these classifications in that it reads into the immediate
> present a set of distinctions — I/not-I; being/not-being;
> thinker/thought; identity/non-identity — that then can proliferate
> into mental and physical conflict. The conceit inherent in this
> perception thus forms a fetter on the mind. To become unbound, one
> must learn to examine these distinctions — which we all take for
> granted — to see that they are simply assumptions that are not
> inherent in experience, and that we would be better off to be able to
> drop them.
>
> [Snp 4.14](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.14.than.html)

Answer (score 1):

If by reification you mean "looking with your brain and only seeing what you already know" then yes, of course it is possible to be free from it. That's exactly what Buddha taught, leaving your preconceptions aside and seeing things as they are.

This is "Yatha-bhuta" and "Beginner's mind".

See [How to practice “In the seen will be merely what is seen"?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/how-to-practice-in-the-seen-will-be-merely-what-is-seen)